# Angular2 - Input-Value undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I want to pass the Input-Value to the function by clicking the Button.

```
<md-card> 
     <md-input-container><input mdInput ngDefaultControl [ngModel]="newInput">
     </md-input-container> 
     <button md-raised-button (click)="newInputValue(newInput)">Update</button>
</md-card>
```

But the value of **newInput** in the function **newInputValue(..)** is always undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the below link you are using property binding(one way), so you cannot access the variable in the DOM

```
 <md-input-container><input mdInput ngDefaultControl [ngModel]="newInput">
```

Change the `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]`

Alternatively,

```
 <div class="button-row">
  <md-input-container><input mdInput #inputVal [ngModel]="newInput">
     </md-input-container> 
     <button md-raised-button (click)="newInputValue(inputVal.value)">Update</button>
  </div>
```

In the above case you will have the value in your method, so your one way databinding remains untouched

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LadAtdjMXHgEcJtJYhS5?p=preview)** of second option